# how to change just the (numbers) font-family in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, fonts

My problem is I can't change just the numbers font-family on WordPress
is there any way to do it with JS or CSS?
Or
is there any simple way to do it with a plugin?

Comment: The CSS property unicode-range lets you do this.

Comment: Can you give me the Unicode range of numbers?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23738423/using-unicode-range-to-exclude-numbers-only